# Reverse Engineer Code First after a database change

Tags: entity-framework, entity

all...

Is there a way of reverse engineering in code first if there has been a minor change by someone within SQL management studio.

The equivalent in the EDMX file would be when you double click on the edmx file and right click and update from the database and it updates your model.

the reason i ask is there is alot of sql changes through SQL management studios and I dont know how I would consistently update my model.

thanks

Comment: Do you have a test database that's got the unmodified schema?

Comment: No test database... I was hoping to use a mocking framework. Why do you ask?

Comment: This would be the equivalent in the database first(edmx) approach...
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/database-first-approach-in-mvc-5-part-3/Images/UpdateTable.jpg

Comment: you can use the visual studio [schema compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh272690%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) tool if you've got a backup or test database to compare against the altered database.  The schema comparison will identify the variances between databases.

Comment: Thanks, Jake. I was looking for something automated. Ive heard T4 templates may work, have you used these before?

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse engineer selected objects and then add them back to your models and context. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me.
Just so I am clear..there is no way to simply run an update on the classes they have to be re-created, old classes removed and new classes copied in?
Thanks

Comment: The premise of code first is making your changes in the models and letting EF update the database to match. If you are starting out with an existing database or have added objects via SQL, then you need to reverse engineer them into the models with one of the available techniques. VS2013 has a schema compare utility you could use to get things synchronized.

Comment: Have you ever used t4 templates for generating the classes ?

Comment: Yes, I've actually customized the reverse engineer templates because I was bringing in a lot of legacy stuff: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx

Comment: Thanks, @Steve Greene ... Ill have a more in depth look at this link.

Comment: ill probably go down the t4 template route!.. Thanks!